# what does "the of" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

> Cultural background affects *the of* individuals.

I found this sentence on Nature Human Behavior. But I couldn't find any meaning or usage of "the of".

I assuming that there would be some kind of missing words like:

> Cultural background affects *the characteristic of* individuals.

What do you think about this assumption? or the original sentence was correct?

Comment: Looks like an error. Do you have a link to the orginal source?

Comment: @JamesK  You may have to pay to see the original article. but I copy&pasted, so what you see above is quite original.

Comment: actually you edited, since the orgininal https://www.nature.com/articles/s41562-018-0488-z?WT.feed_name=subjects_physics has "... structure in the English edition, cultural background affects the of individuals; therefore, the results of those studies may not be generalizable."  You have removed the first part of the sentence, changed to a captial C and changed the semi-colon to a full stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The sentence as written is wrong and has no meaning.